# ID3DXFont : Text is stretched, how to get font's width & height?

Tags: c++, fonts, directx

I'm trying to add font support to my custom game engine. I'm using C++ and DirectX 9 with VS2012. The problem : when you create a ID3DXFont object, you have to specify separately the width & height of the characters, but the aspect (width / height) is different for different fonts, thus making one font stretched, another normal.

- stretched "OCR A Extended" font: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8OsM.jpg
- normal "Pristina" font: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8zfE.jpg

I tried searching on Google and other forums for a possible function to get those two values from the system or other sources, but no luck on that...

Right now, I'm giving the inputs by hand :

```cpp
ID3DXFont* f;
D3DXCreateFont(
        m_context->getD3Ddevice(),
        size, size / 4.0F,   // this part is the issue
        FW_REGULAR,
        0,
        false,
        DEFAULT_CHARSET,
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        DRAFT_QUALITY,
        DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE,
        m_name,
        &f );
```

This code hasn't been modified, it is the one that operated the text showed by the two pictures above.

Comment: "VS2012" - Wow, old-school. You may want to upgrade that and take advantage of C++17 and all the improvements that have been made in the last (almost) 10 years..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I missed a crucial help from Microsoft there : DirectX Samples (from the DirectX SDK).

There was obviously one on how to draw text, and the solution was to just simply enter 0 for the width parameter :

```cpp
D3DXCreateFont(
        m_context->getD3Ddevice(),
        size, 0,   // In order, height & width
        FW_REGULAR,
        0,
        false,
        DEFAULT_CHARSET,
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        DRAFT_QUALITY,
        DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE,
        m_name,
        &f );
```